# How to use USB tethering on Mac

Tags: macos, usb, tethering

I want to connect my Android phone mobile Hotspot with my Mac.
I see one has to use Horndis to do that, but it seems very complicated
Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Please try to provide more detail. How does the title link with the question? Are you looking for a solution using USB tethering? What research have you done so far? What have you tried and how didn't it work?

Comment: Also, what is Horndis? Does it have to be USB or would WLAN work as well?